# How to display a colon (":") character on a button?

Tags: c#

I am trying to display on a button string: "MAIN DISK W:\"
The code I am using is:

```
btn_disk.Text = @"MAIN DISK W:\" ;
```

On the screen I see:  `"\:MAIN DISK W"`

But when the code is:

```
btn_disk.Text = @"MAIN DISK W:\PGM"
```

it displays correctly: `"MAIN DISK W:\PGM"`

I tried:

```
btn_disk.Text = @"MAIN DISK W:" ;
```

On the screen I see: `":MAIN DISK W"`

Any ideas why?

Comment: What platform is this?  Winforms?  WPF?  Xamarin?  Webforms?

Comment: In your examples you have the `:` at the front, that is how it looks? Can you take a screenshot of the 3 examples and put them in the question?

Comment: Could someone look at my edit?  The first example of what he sees on his screen was changed in my edit, but I have no idea why.

Comment: LTR/RTL marks in the string?

Comment: I tried to recreate this in winforms, unable to recreate. It worked fine for me. I know this is a baseless suggestion, but could you try the same thing on a new button and see if it continues to happen...

Comment: I am using Win7 with Visual Studio Express 2012 with Microsoft Visual C# 2012.  I created pictures of the screen but I don't see an option to attach it. The only difference is the buttons are very wide. I tried to shortened it - but no change, the same results

Answer (score 1):

If you have enabled `RightToLeft` you will get this outcome.  See if you have that set to `Yes` and disable it to verify.

That setting interprets the ":" as punctuation at the end of a text line and moves it to the opposite side for a `RightToLeft` language.

I am not sure how to get your output correct if you need `RightToLeft` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

did you try the following?

```
btn_disk.Text = "MAIN DISK W:\\";
```

it should work...

Comment: He is using `@` before the string to indicate a verbatim string.  This shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Brian from the state farm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4167186/brian-from-state-farm) for the suggestion. I started to play with different options and found that option Text Allign - MiddleLeft fixed my display.

zb